# how get a list of Triggers registered to a Quartz scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I need to build a gui showing some kind of 'job queue'.

I create triggers dynamically and schedule them with `jobScheduler.scheduleJob(trigger);`. I pass also some data via the trigger's dataMap.

How can I get back the list of triggers which didn't yet fire?

I found a way to get the currently running jobs, but no way to get the list of registered trigger.

Should I maintain this list by myself and remove stuff when it finished executing by implementing a trigger listener?

Can I get the underlying JobStore and invoke getTriggerNames() or similar? But how can I get the JobStore. All I have is a Scheduler instance (actualy a StdScheduler), and there seems no way to get a JobStore instance from it.

(I use spring to get the Scheduler from a SchedulerFactoryBean)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I'm just tired.

There **is** a method getTriggerNames() in the Scheduler. So it solves my problem.

Comment: As a later reference, there is no longer the method since Quartz 2 released in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

With modern Quartz (and a bit of unnecessary Spring DSL) if you don't know job or group name:

```
@Autowired
private Scheduler scheduler;

public void x() {
    scheduler.getTriggerKeys(GroupMatcher.anyGroup()).stream()...;
    // like
    scheduler.getTriggerKeys(GroupMatcher.anyGroup()).stream()
            .filter(__ -> {
                try {
                    return "YYY".equals(scheduler.getTrigger(__)
                            .getJobDataMap().getString("myParam"));
                } catch (SchedulerException e) { return false; }
            });
    // or like
    scheduler.getTriggerKeys(GroupMatcher.anyGroup()).stream()
            .filter(__ -> "YYY".equals(__.getName()));
}
```